# why do we declare public classes in individual files?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am new to Java programming, i created one class with name as Demo and saved as sample.java while compile this java program it giving compilation error as below

```
  public class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is year");
                }
            }
```

**sample.java:3: class Demo  is public, should be declared in a file named Demo .java**

why do we declare public classes in individual files......

Thanks

Mukthyar

Comment: then what about default(no specifier) mentioned to class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Oli Charlesworth is right: this is required by Java language specification. You can probably ask why do they require this? The possible answer is to make things clear. Class is atomic unit by definition. You can replace class by its other version and if the public interface was not changed everything will continue working.

So, Java language designers decided to force us to store each classes in separate files.

They just did some exception for non-public classes. Several non-public classes can be saved in one file. I think that the reason is that non-public class is a kind of gory details of the implementation that can be changed at any time by author. Since class is non-public these changes should not affect any API user.

But I strongly recommend you to save every class (even if it is not public) in separate file. This improves code readability and in the end of the day its quality.

Comment: In actuality, the restriction of one public class per compilation unit was to avoid the compiler having to make an extra pass through all the compilation units, in order to determine which classes were where. It is a holdover from Oak (what Java was called before it was Java), though it still makes sense for the current compiler

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what the Java specification requires (or at least, it allows implementations to require this; see Jon's comment below).

---

As to "why", I can only hypothesise.  But it's evident that the designers of Java were very keen on clear coding conventions, etc.  One public class per source file means there's no ambiguity about where to find something.

(If there's a technical reason, I'm not aware of it.)

Comment: Well, it's what the Java specification *allows* to be required by a particular implementation - and it so happens that most implementations *do* use that requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer really answers the "why" question.  This tells me that it _is_ required, but not why it should be required.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: This question is similar to "why is package the default accessibility?"; the answer is because the language says so.

Comment: (I guess I want to answer "why does the language say so.")

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR : To reduce the conceptual complexity of the software.

If you have many public classes hidden in files that have unrelated names makes it much more harder to see the conceptual structure of the programm just by looking at the package structure.

@because the java spec says so - I think the real question is the reasoning behind the spec

Comment: @user1428152 am I? At what point? You might have misunderstood my answer - I am trying to explain the WHY behind the decision to disallow such declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It's to stop people cluttering up files with hundreds of classes in non orthogonally named files. The namespacepart/namespacepart/namespacepart/classname structure is there to provide a standard and sustainable structure.